# Кириллица в таблице mysql

Tags: mysql, кодировка

Есть таблица, в которой хранятся записи на русском языке. Кодировки у столбцов разные(utf8_unicode_ci, cp1251_general_ci, utf8_general_ci, utf8_bin). После подключения к базе прописываю:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES cp1251");
```

В выводе все значения, где были русские слова(не зависит от кодировки) равны null.
Если не прописывать,то в выводе вместо русских букв идут знаки вопроса. Как это исправить? 
P.S. Кодировка таблицы utf8_general_ci. Кодировку браузера пытался ставить и на **cp1251** и на **utf8**, не помогло.

Comment: вроде это php? если да то кодировка должна быть UTF-8. В любом случае попробуйте. кстати если действительно php то mysql устарело Вам как минимум mysqli нужен

Comment: Вывод ни чем не фильтруется? Например, функцией htmlspecialchars()? Попрбуйте написать простейший скрипт, который выводит из таблицы нефильтрованные даные. Так как установка кодировки соединения должна приводить к тому, что MySQL должна корректно обрабатывать ваши данные, получая и отдавая их в Windows-1251, а храня в таблицах именно в тех кодировках, которые вы указали.

Answer (score 1):

Если вместо русских значений вы получаете пустые строки, с высокой долей вероятности вы фильтруете текст при помощи функции `htmlspecialchars()`. Третий параметр данной функции позволяет задавать кодировку текста. К сожалению, в последних версиях PHP с ним творилась совершенная чехорда. Сначала он по умолчанию задавался в ISO-кодировке, поэтому без явного указания кодировки можно было получить пустую строку, затем ISO-кодировку поменяли на UTF-8, теперь кодировка по умолчанию задается при помощи директивы `default_charset` из конфигурационного файла php.ini.

В зависимости от версии PHP вы можете попасть в ситуацию, когда русский текст, даже в кодировке UTF8, не будет по умолчанию выводиться при помощи `htmlspecialchars()`. В этом случае задайте директиве `default_charset` значение UTF8

```
default_charset = "UTF-8"
```

Если это не поможет задайте строку "UTF-8" в качестве третьего параметра функции `htmlspecialchars()`.

```
echo htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_NOQUOTES, "UTF-8");
```